# Spring IncorrectLine Length exception

Tags: spring, batch-processing

Reading text file using `FlatFileItemReader` from 0-326 characters. If 1 line does not have 326 characters I see

> IncorrectLineLengthException: Line is shorter than max range 326.

Since, I have added skip to skip the error. The job completes but, the file cannot be deleted in the `@AfteJob` method.Only way to delete the file is stop the server and delete manually. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you close the reader?

Comment: im assuming spring will close since, im using their implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(job.getExitStatus().equals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED) || job.getExitStatus().equals(ExitStatus.FAILED)){ //Your file deleting logic }
```